# Passing Variable in google Service function

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api

I am using the DistanceMatrixService of the Google APII am trying to pass the variable **'resto'** when i call the getDistanceMatrix function, so that when i get the response, i can further use that variable.
  My function looks like this:

```
                var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
                var resto = listRestaurant[i];
                service.getDistanceMatrix({
                    origins: [ new google.maps.LatLng(locationCurrent.coords.latitude, locationCurrent.coords.longitude) ] ,
                    destinations: [ resto.address ],
                //Here i am trying to pass the variable 'resto'
                },function ( response , status , resto ){
                    if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
                        alert('Error was: ' + status);
                    } else {
                        if( response.rows[0].elements[0].distance !=null  ){
                            //Further use variable
                            console.log( resto );
                            callGeocoder( resto  );
                        }
                    }
                });
```

But the log returns **'undefined variable'**

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not pass the variable, you define a function-argument.

The parameters will be passed internally by the API, and the only parameters that will be passed are a [`DirectionsResult`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsResult) and a [`DirectionsStatus`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsStatus), there is no way to pass additional parameters.

You may use a anonymous function to make the variable available in the callback:

```
             var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();

            (
              function(resto){
                service.getDistanceMatrix({
                  origins: [ new google.maps.LatLng(locationCurrent.coords.latitude, 
                                                    locationCurrent.coords.longitude) ] ,
                  destinations: [ resto.address ],
                    //note:travelMode is required too
                  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
                },function ( response , status ){
                if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
                    alert('Error was: ' + status);
                } else { 
                    if( response.rows[0].elements[0].distance !=null  ){
                        //Further use variable
                        console.log( resto );
                        callGeocoder( resto  );
                    }
                }
                });
              }
            )(listRestaurant[i]);
```

Comment: Brilliant Man! Thanks Alot! I have never seen that syntax before. (Note: yes thanks, i had removed it from the question as it wasn't related)